# C++ help setting up pointers in classes

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, member

I'm currently having some problems with my class and the member functions, particularly with taking the users input from the setter functions and then displaying that info from the print info function. I have a separate functions that allow the user to enter information about the character and then a getter function to then use in printing out the info that the user entered. When I first ran it I had an error about needing to use a pointer to a member function and I added the &Character::GetCharacterName and the others in my print info function. Now when I run the program through my main function (I didn't include it because it simply calls all the functions) my program will run but all the values are set at 1 no matter what the user entered. I know it has something to do with pointers so any help with correctly setting this up so that it returns the values that the user entered would be appreciated. Thanks

```
Character.h file
class Character
{
public:
    Character();
    void SetCharacterName();
    void SetCharacterType();
    void SetCharacterLevel();
    string GetCharacterName();
    string GetCharacterType();
    double GetCharacterLevel();
    void PrintInfo();

private:
    string CharacterName;
    string CharacterType;
    double CharacterLevel;
};



Character.cpp file
Character::Character()
{
    CharacterLevel = 1.0;
}

void Character::SetCharacterName()
{
    cout << "\nWhat is the character's name? ";
    cin >> CharacterName;
}

void Character::SetCharacterType()
{
    cout << "\nWhat is the character's type? ";
    cin >> CharacterType;
}

void Character::SetCharacterLevel()
{
    cout << "\nWhat is the character's level? ";
    cin >> CharacterLevel;
}

string Character::GetCharacterName()
{
    return CharacterName;
}

string Character::GetCharacterType()
{
    return CharacterType;
}

double Character::GetCharacterLevel()
{
    return CharacterLevel;
}

void Character::PrintInfo()
{
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
    cout << "\nCharacter name is " << &Character::GetCharacterName << ".\n";
    cout << "\nCharacter type is " << &Character::GetCharacterType << ".\n";
    cout << "\nCharacter level is " << &Character::GetCharacterLevel <<    ".\n";
}
```

Comment: Although FPK's answer is right there is no need to use the getters because `PrintInfo()` can access the attributes directly, so you could simply use `std::cout << CharacterName << std::endl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `()`, to do a method call in `PrintInfo`:

```
cout << "\nCharacter name is " << GetCharacterName() << ".\n";
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed my problem, I always manage to miss the little things like that.

Answer (score 1):

I sugest :
this->GetCharacterName();
 In the print method.